# Why are values not updating after asynchronous function?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I am currently creating a project where I need to geocode an address and put that into coordinates. As you can see, I have made the following function down below to do this, and it works. However, The variables that get returned in this function do not seem to update throughout the rest of the app. Here below is my code.

```
var startLat: Double!
var startLong: Double!

typealias theDouble = (Double, Double) -> ()  

func forwardGeocodingStarting(address: String, completion: theDouble){
   //your code
   let aVar: Double!
   let bVar: Double!

   let placemark = placemarks?[0]
   let location = placemark?.location
   let coordinate = location?.coordinate
   aVar = (coordinate?.latitude)!
   bVar = (coordinate?.longitude)!
   completion(aVar, bVar)
}

// CALL THIS FUNCTION 

forwardGeocodingStarting(<your string address>) { firstVar, secondVar in

   startLat = firstVar
   startLong = secondVar
   print("\(startLat) is lat and \(startLong) is long") //GET CORRECT VALUES
}

print(startLat) // GET "NIL"
print(startLong) // GET "NIL"



// ================= EDIT ==============

            if startLat != 0 {
            let startLatUnwrapped: Double = startLat
        }

        if startLong != 0 {
            let startLongUnwrapped: Double = startLong
        }
```

What I need to do is use `startLat` & `startLong` throughout my project, but it does not seem to be updating outside me calling the function. When I call these two variables outside of my function call, it just returns `nil`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `forwardGeocodingStarting` works asynchronously that means the completion block is called later in time. Just put the two `print` lines – or the code to process the values – into the block like the other `print` line.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous block returns control instantly. So, when you call

```
print(startLat)
```

right after the async block, it will not contain updated values (in this case, it contains nil). Instead of using the variables right after the async block, I recommend creating a method that does the desired work on/with the variables and call it at the end of your async closure.

Another way to use the variables safely, is by checking if they're nil. You can use

```
if let
```

to safely unwrap the variables.

Hope this helps.

EDIT

Here is what I meant:

```
forwardGeocodingStarting(<your string address>) { firstVar, secondVar in

    startLat = firstVar
    startLong = secondVar
    print("\(startLat) is lat and \(startLong) is long") //GET CORRECT VALUES

    self.unwrapAndPrintCoordinates()
}

//Now, if anywhere in your code, you want to check if startLat and startLong 
//have values, you call this method

func unwrapAndPrintCoordinates() {

    //Unwrap startLat
    if let startLatUnwrapped = startLat {
        print(startLatUnwrapped)
    }

    //Unwrap startLong
    if let startLongUnwrapped = startLong {
        print(startLongUnwrapped)
    }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit on the bottom of my code to try and address your suggestion, but that does not seem to be working. Is that what you meant with the if let statement?

Comment: You should check the Apple documentation for optional unbinding [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)